# How to resolve an interface and use it in the class using Autofac

Tags: c#, autofac

I'm trying to resolve an interface that I registered in Autofac but it seems to be not working. There is 
nullreferenceexception.

Class where I register the inferface :

```
    public void RegisterAutofac(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

           (...)
        builder.RegisterType<ApiFileTester>().As<IApiFlTester>().InstancePerRequest();

        var container = builder.Build();
        config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

    }
```

Then I want to use it in a class :

```
  public class ApiFileSendingController : ApiClientBase
{
    private readonly IApiFlTester _apiFileTester;

    public ApiFileSendingController(DTO dto, IApiFlTester tester) : base(dto)
    {
        _tester = tester; 
    }


    public void Send(List<AftInvFileDTO> filesToSendRetry = null)
    {
        _apiFileTester.RegisterTestingMethods();
    }

}
```

Then in some other class:

```
DTO dto = new DTO(); //some configuration here

ApiFileSendingController sender = new ApiFileSendingController(dto, null);
sender.Send();
```

There is a problem here because my interface is null. I've tried to pass it like this:

> ApiFileSendingController sender = new ApiFileSendingController(dto,
>   null);

but it's null and it's completely reasonable (I am passing the null).
IS it possible to configure optional parameter or something? I'd like to have this interface resolved automatically by autofac, not manually.

Comment: Is there a reason why you cant add an additional constructor (if optional parameters does not work) that only has the DTO as a parameter? example: `public ApiFileSendingController(DTO dto) : this(dto, null) {}`

Comment: Yes I could add it like this, but then my _apiFileTester is still null.

Comment: Are you saying that in some cases you want to call the constructor but still have Autofac supply the 2nd dependency? It's unclear. If `_apiFileTester` should never be null then write the class so that it can never be null. Throw an exception if the argument is null.

Comment: Yes. I want to call the contructor to provide the dto, but I don't want to provide the IApiFileTester because autofac should resolve it automatically. My problem here is that I am not able to resolve it automatically - my _apiFileTester is null when I try to code it like presented above. Is there any way to change the code to call a contructor and have _apiFileTester containing what I registered in the autofac?

Comment: Don't use `InstancePerRequest()` as stated in the [documentation](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html).  Use `InstancePerLifetimeScope()` instead.

Comment: Much of your code is missing and/or wrong.  You should have a *complete and working* solution to build.

Answer (score 0):

I don't seem to have a problem resolving your class.  Technically it's impossible to really answer your question since the code won't even compile and it appears you have a ton of missing autofac registrations.

[Working Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZJO6QH).

```
// @nuget: Autofac
using System;
using Autofac;

public class Program
{
    private static IContainer _container;

    public static void Main()
    {
        RegisterAutofac();
        using (var httpRequestScope = _container.BeginLifetimeScope("AutofacWebRequest"))
        {
            var apiController = httpRequestScope.Resolve<ApiFileSendingController>();
            Console.WriteLine(apiController._apiFileTester);
        }
    }

    public static void RegisterAutofac()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        //builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        builder.RegisterType<ApiFileTester>().As<IApiFlTester>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterType<ApiFileSendingController>().AsSelf();
        builder.RegisterType<DTO>().AsSelf();
        _container = builder.Build();
    }

    public class ApiFileSendingController : ApiClientBase
    {
        public readonly IApiFlTester _apiFileTester;
        public ApiFileSendingController(DTO dto, IApiFlTester tester): base (dto)
        {
            _apiFileTester = tester;
        }
    }

    public interface IApiFlTester { }
    public class ApiFileTester : IApiFlTester { }
    public class ApiClientBase 
    {
        public ApiClientBase(DTO dto)
        {
        }
    }
    public class DTO { }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have misconception at Autofac DI, most of the DI frameworks are good at creating instances for you, via constructor injection and property injection you will get the instance with their dependencies automatically wired up.
Your constructor contains DTO instance which you will provide during runtime, Autofac will not resolve that since you had not declare it to the DI container during ConfigureServices cycle.

You might need to giving up using Autofac in this case to get the freedom of creating controller instance at your own code, you will need to get the concrete class instance from Reflection instead. The abstraction / implementation isolation is still there via this approach.

public class ApiFileSendingController : ApiClientBase
    {
        private readonly IApiFlTester _apiFileTester;

```
    public ApiFileSendingController(DTO dto, IApiFlTester tester) : base(dto)
    {
       if (tester is null)
        _tester = GetApiTesterViaReflection(); 
       else
        _tester = tester;
    }

    public ApiFileSendingController(DTO dto) : base(dto)
    {
        _apiFileTester = GetApiTesterViaReflection();
    }


    public void Send(List<AftInvFileDTO> filesToSendRetry = null)
    {
        _apiFileTester.RegisterTestingMethods();
    }

    private IApiFlTester GetApiTesterViaReflection()
    {
        Type type = typeof(IApiFlTester).Assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IApiFlTester))).FirstOrDefault();
        return Activator.CreateInstance(type) as IApiFlTester;
    }

}
```